# Django : json serialize a queryset which uses defer() or only()

Tags: django, json, serialization

Now I've been using json serializer and it works great.

I had to modify my queries where I started using the `only()` & `defer()` filters, like so -

```
retObj = OBJModel.objects.defer("create_dt").filter(loged_in_dt__gte=dtStart)
```

After I've done the above, suddenly the json serializer is returning empty fields -

```
{"pk": 19047, "model": "OBJModel_deferred_create_dt", "fields": {}}
```

If I remove the defer(), the serializer gives all the data correctly.

```
import json
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
retObj = OBJModel.objects.defer("create_dt").filter(loged_in_dt__gte=dtStart)
json_serializer.serialize(retObj, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I've scratched my head on this for a while now. Any insight would be great.

**NOTE : I am using django 1.1**

Comment: What type of field is create_dt? Looking at the tickets in Django there's a few bugs on only and defer. Perhaps yours is one of those, or a new bug. I don't see why it would do that without it being a bug. I hope I'm proven wrong though :)

Comment: Its a `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` . And I hope I haven't hid a bug..

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused as to how you would expect the serializer to behave in regards to deferred fields... It is possible that I'm missing something...

The [doc for json serialization](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2) says:

> Be aware that if you're serializing using that module directly, not all Django output can be passed unmodified to simplejson. In particular, lazy translation objects need a special encoder written for them.

The doc is talking about lazy translations, but I think any lazy operation applies.

I think what you are seeing is just the correct output if you haven't written a special encoder of some sort that will take care of obtaining (accessing) the proper value for the deferred fields.

**Edit after your comment:** Ah, I was missing the fact that no other fields are being encoded. What are the types of the other fields? Could we see your model? FK and M2M fields are handled differently by the default encoder - but I don't see anything on `django.core.serializers.python.Serializer` or `django.core.serializers.json.Serializer` that would explain why the other non-deferred fields are not encoding...

**Edit after some further investigation:** The `OBJModel_deferred_create_dt` in your json payload above made me dig a bit further. It seems that is the result of a call to `django.db.models.queryutils.deferred_class_factory()` from the `__reduce__` method in the django's base Model class. The `deferred_class_factory()`:

> Returns a class object that is a copy of "model" with the specified "attrs" being replaced with DeferredAttribute objects. The "pk_value" ties the deferred attributes to a particular instance of the model.

This is where things get murky (to me!): In reality the pickling is being done against a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for your actual `OBJModel`. This proxy model should return - when asked - the non-deferred fields of the original model. But in your case it appears it isn't.

I'll try to set up a small test and see if I can replicate the problem.

Comment: hmm.. when we defer a field that field doesn't get retrieved. But rest of the data is retrieved. Hence when you pass it to JSON it should actually encode it. I can understand it not encoding the deferred fields, but non-deferred ones are already present. What say ?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is a bug of some sort.  Below is a workaround.  Do this before you call serialize.  You will incur a performance hit, but probably less than serializing the entire object.

```
for obj in qs:
    for attr in qs.query.deferred_loading[0]:
        obj._meta.local_fields.append(qs.model._meta.get_field(attr))
```